# Conditional display of rows in Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I've created a WebI report to display all *Transactions Done* for a day for a certain product.

The report works fine, but I've a new requirement wherein the report needs to display `No Records Available` message in case no records match the query and WebI report is empty.

Can this be achieved? If yes... can you please help me with the process?

-Vjai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it....Hopefully It'll help someone else just in case...

Create a variable in the webi using the below Formula....Insert a blank cell and assign it a value of the variable.

Now change the properties of the Cell to Hide when Empty...

```
If NumberofRows(Query1)=0 Then "No Records Available"
```